# I have a problem with UnhandledPromiseRejection don't know how to solve it

Tags: javascript

I'm following a course section with this code and gives me this error:

```
This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a 
catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). 
The promise rejected with the reason "That item is sold out.".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}
```

This is the code:

```
const inventory = {
  sunglasses: 0,
  pants: 1088,
  bags: 1344
};

// Write your code below:
const myExecutor = (resolve, reject) =>{
  if(inventory.sunglasses > 0){
    resolve('Sunglasses order processed.');
  }else{
    reject('That item is sold out.');
  }
}

const orderSunglasses = () => {
  return new Promise(myExecutor);
}

const orderPromise = orderSunglasses();
console.log(orderPromise);
```

I tried to find the error online and reading others Errors, but is not clear, but I have no idea, I am new in javascript.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  The code is doing exactly what it's written to do.  The `Promise` is calling `reject('That item is sold out.')` because the `else` block is executing, because the `if` condition is `false`.  What other behavior were you expecting and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With typical promise consumption, we won’t know whether a promise will resolve or reject, so we’ll need to provide the logic for either case. We can pass both a success callback and a failure callback to `.then()`.

```
const inventory = {
  sunglasses: 0,
  pants: 1088,
  bags: 1344
};

// Write your code below:
let prom = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
  if(inventory.sunglasses > 0){
    resolve('Sunglasses order processed.');
  }else{
    reject('That item is sold out.');
  }
});

const handleSuccess = (resolvedValue) => {
  console.log(resolvedValue);
};
 
const handleFailure = (rejectionReason) => {
  console.log(rejectionReason);
};
 
prom.then(handleSuccess, handleFailure);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const myExecutor = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
  if(inventory.sunglasses > 0){
    resolve('Sunglasses order processed.');
  }else{
    reject('That item is sold out.');
  }
});

const orderSunglasses = () => {
  return myExecutor;
}

const orderPromise = orderSunglasses();
orderPromise.then((value)=>console.log(value)).catch((err)=>console.log(err));
```

use then and catch methods to check if your promise has been resolved or rejected, as it works with two types of values if you don't check for error in the catch block it will throw an error for rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch()